# How can I create a Dynamic DropDownBox in SapUi5?

Tags: javascript, sapui5, dynamic-arrays

I have one test folder in ProjectExplorer . In that folder i have multiple JSON files. I want to create a DropDownBox which will have all the files name containing in that folder. Also , when i click on any file I want to Display that file in a TextArea . I want to do this in SapUi5. Please Suggest

What I have tried so far

```
var oText = new sap.ui.commons.Label({
                text : "Saved Files"
            });

            var SavedFiles = new sap.ui.commons.DropdownBox();
            var oItem = new sap.ui.core.ListItem();


    #!/usr/bin/perl 


    $basedir = "data"; //folder location 

    @files = ('*.json'); 

    chdir($basedir); 
    foreach $file (@files) 
    { 
       $ls = `ls $file`; 
       @ls = split(/\s+/,$ls); 
       foreach $temp_file (@ls) 
       { 
          if (-d $file) 
          { 
             $filename = "$file$temp_file"; 
             if (-T $filename) 
             { 
                push(@FILES,$filename); 
             } 
          } 
          elsif (-T $temp_file) 
          { 
             push(@FILES,$temp_file); 
          } 
       } 
    } 


    foreach $FILE (@FILES) 
    { 
          oItem.setText("filename");
          SavedFiles.addItem(oItem);
    }
```

Comment: I would guess that it's impossible with only JS and SAPUI5. For security reasons you cannot access the directory (where your JSON files are stored) from your browser with JS. You'd need a script on the server that provides the file structure via some kind of API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done, but you need to make the directory browsable.

1. Create a `.htaccess` file in the directory you need to read, and in that file add the following:
   `Options +Indexes`
2. Implement the following:

```js
var aFiles = [];
$.ajax({
    url : "http://localhost:8010/", // or whatever URL you use
    success: function (data) {
        $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
            if( val.match(/\.(json)$/) ) { 
                aFiles.push(val);
            } 
        });
        console.log(aFiles); //aFiles holds an array with all the *.json files
    }
});
```